# Pagination not working :

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I am displaying pagination in my application using following javascript,its working fine for me, but i need to break the pagination after 5 pages

This is my existing pagination

`1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9` `10` `11` `12` `13` `14` `15` `16` `17` `18` `19` `20`

but i need to display the pagination by following

`1` `2` `3` `4` `5` ......`15` `16` `17` `18` `19` `20`

if i click on page number 5 then it should add another 5 pages to current page

My Javscript like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }
    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';
        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';
        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }

    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }

    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1);
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
        var element = document.getElementById(positionId);
        var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> <img src="${ctx}/images/prev.PNG" alt=" « Prev" height="17px" width="26px" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>&nbsp; </span> ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++)
        pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal">&nbsp;<img src="${ctx}/images/nexts.png" alt="Next »" height="17px" width="26px" style="vertical-align: middle;"/></span>';
        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
}


</script>
```

if any suggestion it will be appreciable

here is the  [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yqLyF/)

Comment: @TusharGupta updated jsfiddle

Comment: Since your fiddle only has CSS, I can only guess by your javascript code here: If your showPageNav function is printing the page numbers, then there is your problem. Your for loop prints a numbered link for every page.

Comment: @alex i have updated my fiddle please check it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a new jsfiddle doing what you want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/nye7a/2/

The showPageNav function has been changed like this :

```
this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {

var pageIndex = this.currentPage,
    pageCount = this.pages,
    start = Math.max(1, pageIndex - 4),
    end = Math.min(pageCount, pageIndex + 4),
    start2 = pageCount-4,
    end2 = pageCount;

    if (start2 <= end)
        end = pageCount;

if (! this.inited) {

alert("not inited");

return;

}

var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

var pagerHtml = '';

// adds the Prev button only if needed
if (pageIndex > 1)
    pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> « Prev </span> ';

    // paging from 1 to 5   
    for (var page = start; page <= end; page++) {

pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> ';
    }

    // paging from pageCount-5 to pageCount
    if (end != pageCount) {
         pagerHtml += '<span>...</span>';

        for (var page = start2; page <= end2; page++) {

    pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> ';
        }   
    }

// adds the Next button only if needed
if (pageIndex < pageCount && pageCount > 1)    
    pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next »</span>';

element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but it's not adding 5 more pages when I click on page number 5 and when i click on next button its going to stop the pagination

Comment: In this.showPage function, you can add this line after the line this.currentPage = pageNumber; :  this.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition');